# What is the CCHAR type equivalent in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

The **`ShortNameLength`** member of [FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure is declared as follows:

```
typedef struct FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION {
  ...
  CCHAR  ShortNameLength;
  ...
};
```

From [the explanation of `CCHAR` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CCHAR), `CCHAR` is *a 8-bit Windows (ANSI) character*. So, it is equivalent to **`AnsiChar`** in Delphi, right? However, the description of [ShortNameLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) member of `FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION` structure says,

> ***“`ShortNameLength` specifies the length, in bytes, of the short file name string.”***

The statement makes me think that the **`CCHAR`** equivalent is **`Byte`** in Delphi. Another example is the **`NumberOfProcessors`** member of `SYSTEM_BASIC_INFORMATION` which is declared in `winternl.h` as follows:

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_BASIC_INFORMATION {
  BYTE Reserved1[24];
  PVOID Reserved2[4];
  CCHAR NumberOfProcessors;
}
```

Once again, the `CCHAR` type seems to be used in a `Byte` context, rather than `AnsiChar` context.

Now, I confuse, whether to use `AnsiChar` or `Byte` as a `CCHAR` equivalent in Delphi.

#### Note

`JwaWinType.pas` of [JEDI Windows API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/) declares `CCHAR` as `AnsiChar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a byte, or at least, it is used as a 1 byte integer. In C, chars can be used for this purpose. In Delphi, you couldn't do that without typecasting. So you could use `Char`, but then you would need to give it the value `'A'` or `Chr(65)` to indicate a string of 65 characters. Now, that would be silly. :-)

To be able to pass it to the API it must have the same size. Apart from that, the callee will not even know how it is declared, so declaring it as a Delphi byte is the most logical solution. A choice backed up by the other declaration you found.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the explanation of `CCHAR` is wrong. The `C` prefix indicates that this is a **count** of characters so this is probably a simple copy-paste error done by Microsoft when writing the explanation.

It is stored in a byte and it is used to count the number of bytes of a string of characters. These characters may be wide characters but the `CCHAR` value still counts the number of bytes used to store the characters.

The natural translation for this type is `Byte`. If you marshal it to a character type like `AnsiChar` you will have to convert the character to an integer value (e.g. a byte) before using it.

Comment: Your answer and @GolezTrol's answer is deserved to accept, but I have to choose one. Thanks very much anyway. :-)